# Stackoverflow during complex math on android

Tags: java, android

I am using a hough transform to find circles in an image on android. At once point I get a stack overflow:

```
12-03 16:18:20.999: I/dalvikvm-heap(21563): Grow heap (frag case) to 29.662MB for 2253716-byte allocation
12-03 16:18:21.014: I/dalvikvm(21563): threadid=11: stack overflow on call to Lorg/DTS/boltSizer/ImageProcessing/hystThresh;.hystConnect:VII
12-03 16:18:21.014: I/dalvikvm(21563):   method requires 44+20+12=76 bytes, fp is 0x5e949338 (56 left)
12-03 16:18:21.014: I/dalvikvm(21563):   expanding stack end (0x5e949300 to 0x5e949000)
```

Here is where the error is being thrown:

```
    private void hystConnect(int x, int y) {

        int value = 0;
        for (int x1=x-1;x1<=x+1;x1++) {
            for (int y1=y-1;y1<=y+1;y1++) {
                if ((x1 < width) & (y1 < height) & (x1 >= 0) & (y1 >= 0) & (x1 != x) & (y1 != y)) {
                    value = (input[y1*width+x1])  & 0xff;
                    if (value != 255) {
                        if (value >= lower) {
                            input[y1*width+x1] = 0xffffffff;
                            hystConnect(x1, y1);
                            ran++;

                        } 
                        else {
                            input[y1*width+x1] = 0xff000000;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I think I understand what it means, but how does one go avoiding this. If you need more of the code being ran just ask.

Comment: Are you using any recursion logic?

Comment: You couldn't find any better place to ask about your stackoverflow problems than this one :)

Comment: for (int x1=x-1;x1<=x+1;x1++) this condition always satisfies isn't it?

Comment: FOrgot to mention I have this working in an applet. Same exact code. Runs find on my PC but not on Android. Thats whats confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

Start with this:

[How to increase the Java stack size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700459/how-to-increase-to-java-stack-size)

[Android: Increase call stack size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857602/android-increase-call-stack-size)

Ultimately this just means your function is consuming a *lot* of memory and you will have to find a more efficient algorithm.  This is similar to if you posted an `O(e^n)` function and asked how to make it go faster.  If this is your situation then you will want to research a more space-efficient algorithm to use.